# Sonarqube not running after installing json plugin

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I recently upgraded sonarqube from version 8.8 to 9.9 Community Edition.

I have installed **Sonarqube Community edition version 9.9** which was running perfectly fine on my windows system.

I have some **json codes** which I want to sonarqube to scan, so I found [json-plugin](https://github.com/racodond/sonar-json-plugin) which scans the json file as well.
I download the jar and Put the downloaded jar in `<SONARQUBE_HOME>/extensions/plugins` as mentioned in the sonarqube [documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/setup-and-upgrade/install-a-plugin/)

As soon as I restart the server, the sonarqube does not start by giving the following error:

```
D:\sonarqube-9.9.0.65466\bin\windows-x86-64>StartSonar.bat
Starting SonarQube...
2023.04.12 18:38:14 INFO  app[][o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory D:\sonarqube-9.9.0.65466\temp
2023.04.12 18:38:14 INFO  app[][o.s.a.es.EsSettings] Elasticsearch listening on [HTTP: 127.0.0.1:9001, TCP: 127.0.0.1:51323]
2023.04.12 18:38:14 INFO  app[][o.s.a.ProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[ELASTICSEARCH] from [D:\sonarqube-9.9.0.65466\elasticsearch]: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin\java -XX:+UseG1GC -Djava.io.tmpdir=D:\sonarqube-9.9.0.65466\temp -XX:ErrorFile=D:\sonarqube-9.9.0.65466\logs\es_hs_err_pid%p.log -Des.networkaddress.cache.ttl=60 -Des.networkaddress.cache.negative.ttl=10 -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch -Xss1m -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djna.nosys=true -Djna.tmpdir=D:\sonarqube-9.9.0.65466\temp -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true -Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization=true -Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacityPerThread=0 -Dio.netty.allocator.numDirectArenas=0 -Dlog4j.shutdownHookEnabled=false -Dlog4j2.disable.jmx=true -Dlog4j2.formatMsgNoLookups=true -Djava.locale.providers=COMPAT -Dcom.redhat.fips=false -Xmx512m -Xms512m -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=256m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Delasticsearch -Des.path.home=D:\sonarqube-9.9.0.65466\elasticsearch -Des.path.conf=D:\sonarqube-9.9.0.65466\temp\conf\es -cp lib/* org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch
2023.04.12 18:38:14 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Waiting for Elasticsearch to be up and running
2023.04.12 18:38:34 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[es] is up
2023.04.12 18:38:34 INFO  app[][o.s.a.ProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[WEB_SERVER] from [D:\sonarqube-9.9.0.65466]: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin\java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djava.io.tmpdir=D:\sonarqube-9.9.0.65466\temp -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=java.base/jdk.internal.ref=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.nio=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.management/sun.management=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=jdk.management/com.sun.management.internal=ALL-UNNAMED -Dcom.redhat.fips=false -Xmx512m -Xms128m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=localhost|127.*|[::1] -cp ./lib/sonar-application-9.9.0.65466.jar;D:\sonarqube-9.9.0.65466\lib\jdbc\h2\h2-2.1.214.jar org.sonar.server.app.WebServer D:\sonarqube-9.9.0.65466\temp\sq-process3341444263512329691properties
WARNING: A terminally deprecated method in java.lang.System has been called
WARNING: System::setSecurityManager has been called by org.sonar.process.PluginSecurityManager (file:/D:/sonarqube-9.9.0.65466/lib/sonar-application-9.9.0.65466.jar)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.sonar.process.PluginSecurityManager
WARNING: System::setSecurityManager will be removed in a future release
2023.04.12 18:38:44 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[Web Server] is stopped
2023.04.12 18:38:44 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[ElasticSearch] is stopped
2023.04.12 18:38:44 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] SonarQube is stopped
```

PS: The same approached worked with the **sonarqube 8.8 version**

Also, when I delete the plugin from the folder and starts the sonarqube server, it starts working.

Comment: You may want to post this question to [Sonar Community Forum](https://community.sonarsource.com/c/sq/10)

Comment: Hi @MustafaÖzçetin I posted on community as well.

Comment: If you resolve your issue from the forum then please share the fix here for future reference.

Comment: Not a resolution, but an update "The JSON plugin is no longer maintained by its maintainer, so it may no longer support newer versions of SonarQube."